# NSOperation's released at queue ending

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have lots of UIImage batching operations. I add them in once with in an instance of NSOperationQueue :

```
self.operationQueue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: false)
```

But it seems operationQueue captures all the operations and release them after all of them are finished.

My operation instances inherite from this [class](https://gist.github.com/calebd/93fa347397cec5f88233)

How can I release an operation that just finished ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinish:false)` does not implicitly retain all the operations until completion, it is essentially the same as `for operation in operations { addOperation(operation) }`.  Proof is below.

You may be looking at a bug with your operation where it never successfully transitions to/emits `isFinished`.  This seems unlikely if your operations are eventually deallocating when all of them complete.

What seems more likely is that you may have some completion code somewhere with a dependency on these operations:

- You could have a closure maintaining a reference to `operations`.
- You could have a dependent operation: `operation.addOperation(...)`
- You could call `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()` on the queue, which will hold a reference to the operations until they all complete.

#### Proof

You can prove operations are not being retained past completion with the following playground:

```
import Foundation

class Operation: NSOperation {
    let id:Int
    init(id:Int) { self.id = id }
    override func main() { usleep(useconds_t(id * 100000)) }
    deinit { print("Deiniting \(id)") }
}

let queue = NSOperationQueue()

do {
    let operations = (0..<50).map(Operation.init)
    queue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: false)
}

for i in 0..<50 {
    usleep(200000)
    print("Heartbeat")
}
```

You will see instances deallocating at regular intervals while the loop runs.

> ```
> Deiniting 0
> Deiniting 1
> Heartbeat
> Deiniting 2
> Deiniting 3
> Heartbeat
> Deiniting 4
> Deiniting 5
> ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I'll investigate that !